# Calling virtual method resulting in bus error?

Tags: c++

```
class Shape {
    bool intersectP(Ray &ray) {
        return false;
    }
};

class Sphere : public Shape {
    bool intersectP(Ray &ray) {
        return true;
    }
};

class GeometricPrimitive {
    Shape* shape;
    bool intersectP(Ray &ray) {
        return shape->intersectP(ray);
    }
}

bool run() {
    Shape sphere = Sphere(0, 0, -2, 1);
    GeometricPrimitive primitive1 = GeometricPrimitive();
    primitive1.shape = &sphere;

    // generate ray 
    // ...

    return primitive1.intersectP(ray)
}
```

My problem is that `run()` returns `false` rather than `true`. Furthermore, if I change the definition of `intersectP` in `class Shape` to `virtual bool intersectP(Ray &ray)`, then I get a bus error. Any ideas?

Comment: You should keep the intersectP method as virtual itself. But the sphere in run should be either of type reference to Shape or a pointer to Shape, in order to work. i.e Shape * sphere = new Sphere( 0, 0, -2, 1 );

Comment: This results in a Seg Fault for me whether or not I have the `virtual` keyword in the `intersectP` method.

Comment: primitive1 is not initialized

Comment: you may also want to declare a virtual destructor in the base class

Comment: I've updated my OP with a new definition of `run()` -- still Bus Error'ing.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
GeometricPrimitive* primitive1;
primitive1->shape = &sphere;
```

is UB (Undefined Behavior). The reason is that `primitive1` is a pointer that has not been allocated an object, but it's dereferenced to set a member.

If you don't understand why you need to allocate objects probably it would be better to first clear up that issue before moving on virtual methods.

Comment: Thanks, I see; however, I've updated my OP with a new definition of `run()` and am still Bus Error'ing.